# parsing a xhr.responseText response

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to get the xhr.responseText response after consuming a web service, when I executed this code:

```
if (xhr.readyState === 4)
{
       alert("result "+xhr.responseText);
}
```

I get this response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<double xmlns="http://www.webserviceX.NET/">0.4498</double>
```

I would like to get the 0.4498 value!

thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You should use responseXML to parse XML:

```
var xmlDoc = xhr.responseXML;
var d = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("double")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
```

or can use regexp also:

```
/>([\d.]+)</.exec(xhr.responseText)[1]
```